# how to implement authentication socket io?

Tags: python, cookies, websocket, socket.io, fastapi

I am using python fastapi as my backend and after successful login, I am sending jwt token and refresh token from my server to the client browser.

fasapi backend code for sending token:

```
        access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": schema.email_address_mobile_number})
        response.set_cookie(key="bearer", value=access_token, httponly=True, samesite="lax", secure=True)
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(data={"sub": schema.email_address_mobile_number})
        response.set_cookie(key="refresh_token", value=refresh_token, httponly=True, samesite="lax", secure=True)
```

my axois code and from there I want to emit an event for sending cookies to socket io server:

```
 axois.post(url,formData,{withCredentials:true}).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
      //router.push('/');

    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log
    })
```

my socket io code:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user connected');
  
  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
   
    console.log(data)   
    io.emit("admin",data) //only auhenticated login user can get this event 
    io.emit("public","all user even unauthenticated user can get this event")
  
      
  });

 ;
});
```

You can see I am emitting two events one for admin they must be login and another for public and they don't need to login. How to do that?